# How to select only one row from multiple rows with the same field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day.

I have sql query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 
    p.id_price as p_id_price, 
    p.id_service as p_id_service, 
    p.name as p_name, 
    p.name_original as p_name_original, 
    p.id_producer_country as p_id_producer_country, 
    p.id_firm as p_id_firm, 
    f.name as f_name, 
    f.priority as f_priority, 
    f.address as f_address, 
    f.phone as f_phone, 
    city.name as city_name, 
    pc.name as pc_name 
FROM Price p 
    left join Firm f on f.id_service = p.id_service AND f.id_city = p.id_city AND f.id_firm = p.id_firm 
    left join City city on city.id_city = p.id_city left join Producer_country pc on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country 
    left join Dogovor d on d.id_service=p.id_service AND d.id_city=p.id_city AND d.id_firm=p.id_firm 
WHERE 
    id_price NOT IN ( 
        SELECT TOP 20 p.id_price 
        FROM Price p 
            left join Firm f on f.id_service = p.id_service AND f.id_city = p.id_city AND f.id_firm = p.id_firm 
            left join City city on city.id_city = p.id_city 
            left join Producer_country pc on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country 
            left join Dogovor d on d.id_service=p.id_service AND d.id_city=p.id_city AND d.id_firm=p.id_firm 
        WHERE p.id_city='73041' AND p.include='1' AND p.blocked='0' AND f.blocked='0' AND f.dogovor='1' 
                AND d.end_date >= '20131108 02:37:03' 
                AND (p.name LIKE '% tes_ %' OR p.name LIKE 'tes_ %' OR p.name LIKE '% _tes_%') 
        ORDER BY f.priority DESC 
                    ) 
AND p.id_city='73041' 
AND p.include='1' 
AND p.blocked='0' 
AND f.blocked='0' 
AND f.dogovor='1' 
AND d.end_date >= '20131108 02:37:03' 
AND (p.name LIKE '% tes_ %' OR p.name LIKE 'tes_ %' OR p.name LIKE '% _tes_%') 

ORDER BY f.priority DESC
```

But it query selects and outputs multiple rows with the same value of the field **f.name**

Tell me please how selected only one row from multiple rows with the same value of the field  **f.name** ?

***Please tell me how to do line numbers within the same f.name and then select the first number?***

Comment: Are other columns different when `f.name` is the same?

Comment: This is known as `GROUP BY` go ahead and read about it http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @Yosi [Please don't link to w3schools.](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Szymon when `f.name` is the same, colums can have different values or the same. If there are multiple rows with the same field, I need get any of the rows, but only one row from rows with same column `f.name`

Comment: @Yosi please write all finish code in answer

Comment: Do you need any one random row for each f.name? As grouping is not obvious, you seem to have quite a few string fields.

Comment: @michaelb958 - please read this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource and explain why..

Comment: @Szymon i ont know how make group in may example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Top(20) * FROM (
SELECT  Row_Number()OVER(PARTITION BY f.name ORDER BY f.priority, p.datetime DESC) AS NameOrder, 
    p.id_price as p_id_price, 
    p.id_service as p_id_service, 
    p.name as p_name, 
    p.name_original as p_name_original, 
    p.id_producer_country as p_id_producer_country, 
    p.id_firm as p_id_firm, 
    f.name as f_name, 
    f.priority as f_priority, 
    f.address as f_address, 
    f.phone as f_phone, 
    city.name as city_name, 
    pc.name as pc_name 
FROM Price p 
    left join Firm f on f.id_service = p.id_service AND f.id_city = p.id_city AND f.id_firm = p.id_firm 
    left join City city on city.id_city = p.id_city left join Producer_country pc on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country 
    left join Dogovor d on d.id_service=p.id_service AND d.id_city=p.id_city AND d.id_firm=p.id_firm 
WHERE 
    id_price NOT IN ( 
        SELECT TOP 20 p.id_price 
        FROM Price p 
            left join Firm f on f.id_service = p.id_service AND f.id_city = p.id_city AND f.id_firm = p.id_firm 
            left join City city on city.id_city = p.id_city 
            left join Producer_country pc on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country 
            left join Dogovor d on d.id_service=p.id_service AND d.id_city=p.id_city AND d.id_firm=p.id_firm 
        WHERE p.id_city='495' AND p.include='1' AND p.blocked='0' AND f.blocked='0' AND f.dogovor='1' 
                AND d.end_date >= '20131108 02:37:03' 
                AND (p.name LIKE '% tes_ %' OR p.name LIKE 'tes_ %' OR p.name LIKE '% _tes_%') 
        ORDER BY f.priority DESC 
                    ) 
AND p.id_city='495' 
AND p.include='1' 
AND p.blocked='0' 
AND f.blocked='0' 
AND f.dogovor='1' 
AND d.end_date >= '20131108 02:37:03' 
AND (p.name LIKE '% tes_ %' OR p.name LIKE 'tes_ %' OR p.name LIKE '% _tes_%')
)
AS S WHERE S.NameOrder = 1
ORDER BY S.f_priority
```

Answer (score 0):

`Group BY` is not necessarily an easy concept. So yes please stop just sharing links from W3 schools. Its better to explain it.

If you need some sort of aggregation meaning you want to know how many times John comes up you would need to add a column to the end like `COUNT(fname)` and then do a `group by` listing every column you selected.

If you are trying to just show the most unique values you use `DISTINCT`. So after your `SELECT` just add `DISTINCT` and you will get only those rows where each column value is unique.

Comment: im need get not all unique rows. im need Нумеровать строки в пределах одинаковых f.name. Need line numbers within the same f.name. Then select the first number. But i ont know how make it...